# jQuery .live() on JS function - What event to use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic, live

I'm trying to have a setInterval function to use .live() to get information from dynamic content loaded with AJAX. Here's what I have.

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function () { 
       var msgid = $(".msgid:last").attr("id");
       alert (msgid);
    }, 5000);
```

Obviously this does not work on content that is loaded with AJAX. I can't seem to find any event that could be used for the live() function in this case. All I need is to fetch the last msgid that is loaded on the page every 5 seconds.

Any advice?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine? 
http://jsfiddle.net/tftd/YNGur/

Comment: As @tftd says, this code works fine. You don't need to use `live` at all because you are fetching `msgid` from the DOM at the time of execution.

Comment: You also shouldn't want to use `live` as it is deprecated in the latest version of jQuery.

Comment: Wow. You guys are right. The test file I was using was cached in the browser. This explains why it wasn't working (duh). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As the guys mentioned as comments, your code seems to work, so I can only assume that you want a different way to handle it, perhaps something a little more 'jquery-esque'?

If all your requests are similar, and you know how to parse the response, you could try having a global handler...

```
$('body').ajaxSuccess(function(e,x,o) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(x);
    console.log(o);
})
```

as seen [on the jquery website](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)